# How do I fill in the color for this triangle that I made from three lines?

Tags: java

So, my teacher wanted us to make a house for a project this weekend, and I can figure out how to fill in the color for my triangle that I am using for a roof. I am very new at java, so my code is rather ruff, but if anyone could help me, that would be great!(Note that my teacher doesn't really care about code length, just that we figure out house to do it).
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HouseMaker
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(3000, 3000);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

      HouseComponent component = new HouseComponent();
      frame.add(component);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Polygon;

/*
   A component that draws an house with a sun and other things
*/
public class HouseComponent extends JComponent
{  
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      // Recover Graphics2D 
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // Draw the house frame
      g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
      Rectangle frame = new Rectangle(300, 400, 500, 230);
      g2.fill(frame);

      // Draw the roof
      Line2D.Double roof = new Line2D.Double(300, 400, 800, 400);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.drawLine(300, 400, 550, 200);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.drawLine(800, 400, 550, 200);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.draw(roof);

      //sun in the sky
      g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g.drawOval(50,50,100,100);
      g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g2.fillOval(50,50,100,100);
      g2.drawLine(50,50,20,20);
      g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g2.drawLine(150,150,180,180);
      g2.drawLine(150,50,180,20);
      g2.drawLine(50,150,20,180);
      g2.drawLine(30,100,-10,100);
      g2.drawLine(100,30,100,-10);
      g2.drawLine(170,100,210,100);
      g2.drawLine(100,170,100,210);

      //Draw the door

      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      Rectangle door = new Rectangle(450, 510, 50, 120);
      g2.fill(door);

      //Draw door knob
      g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g2.drawOval(450,560,10,10);
      g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g2.fillOval(450,560,10,10);

      //Draw three windows

      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      Rectangle window = new Rectangle(350, 520, 50, 50);
      g2.fill(window);
      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      Rectangle window1 = new Rectangle(550, 520, 50, 50);
      g2.fill(window1);
      g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      Rectangle window2 = new Rectangle(650, 520, 50, 50);
      g2.fill(window2);

      //Draw window panes
      g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g2.drawLine(350,545,400,545);
      g2.drawLine(375,520,375,570);
      g2.drawLine(550,545,600,545);
      g2.drawLine(575,520,575,570);
      g2.drawLine(650,545,700,545);
      g2.drawLine(675,520,675,570);

      //Draw ground
      g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, 630, 1500, 1500);
      g2.fill(ground);
   }
}
```

Comment: To draw a triangle and fill it, don't use three calls to `drawLine()`. Draw it using `drawPolygon()`, and fill it using `fillPolygon()`. Down-voting question for lack of research, since a simple read of the javadoc for [`Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) would have shown the `fill` methods available.

Comment: That's the thing though. I don't know how to use drawPolygon. I've been researching it as an option, but I do not understand how to use it. When I try, it does not work.

Comment: How do you draw a triangle now? Using 3 `x,y` points, and draw a line from A to B, B to C, and C back to A. That also happens to be a closed [**polygon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon). A shape defined by 3 `x,y` points. [`fillPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon-int:A-int:A-int-): *Fills a closed polygon defined by arrays of x and y coordinates.*

Comment: Oh, @Andreas, just forget it. He's using a `Graphics2D` already, surely you can do better than suggest the antiquated `Graphics.fillPolygon`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help man. But she doesn't want us to use polygons, so I will use Adrian's method. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe is time to learn something new?

```
/* Have a look over java.awt.geom.GeneralPath*/
// Draw the roof
GeneralPath shape=new GeneralPath();
shape.moveTo(300, 400)
shape.lineTo(800, 400);
shape.lineTo(550, 200);
shape.closePath(); // easier than shape.lineTo(300, 400);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);
g2.fill(shape);

// let's get a tinge of pink for the outline;
Stroke origStroke=g2.getStroke(); // just to restore it afterwards
g2.setColor(Color.PINK);
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f)); // WHOA, is that something new?
g2.draw(shape); // reusing it, why bother creating other lines?

// as we don't want the next drawing to go with a thin line,
// restore the old stroke
g2.setStroke(origStroke);
```

Comment: Or `p = new Polygon(); p.addPoint(300, 400); p.addPoint(800, 400); p.addPoint(550, 200); g2.fillPolygon(p);`. --- Or simply `g2.fillPolygon(new int[] { 300, 800, 550 }, new int[] { 400, 400, 200}, 3);`

Comment: Thanks you so much! That really helps. We haven't learned how to use polygons yet, and she said she wanted us to use 3 lines to make the triangle, so I'm glad to know that there is a non-polygon solution!

Comment: @Andreas Try then: `p.curveTo(...)`. My point? `GeneralPath` does anything that `Polygon` does and a bit (actually a lot) more.